# Azure Diagnostic - Output TraceSource to Log Stream on Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to get trace output from a particular trace source onto Azure Portal's Log Stream. However, this does not seem to work

```xml
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="txtListener" 
           type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
           initializeData="SchoolsDirectoryLog.log" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="SkyNet" switchName="sourceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="txtListener" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="sourceSwitch" value="Error, Information, Warning, Verbose" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: What **exactly** does not work?

Comment: That I could not see the output from that source when using the Log Stream  on Azure Portal. Locally, It works fine.